# How to check if value is not null or empty and then only concatenate in terraform list(maps)?

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

I have two different `list(maps)` inside a local block, named `boot_disk` and `add_disk`

```
locals {

 boot_disk = [
    {
      source_image = var.source_image 
      disk_size_gb = var.disk_size_gb
      disk_type    = var.disk_type
      disk_labels  = var.disk_labels
      auto_delete  = var.auto_delete
      mode = "READ_WRITE"
      boot         = "true"
    }
  ]

  add_disk= [
    {
      source_image = var.add_source_image 
      disk_size_gb = var.add_disk_size_gb
      disk_type    = var.add1DiskType
      auto_delete  = var.additional_disk_auto_delete
      boot         = "false"
      mode = "READ_WRITE"
    }]

  all_disk=concat(local.boot_disk,local.add_disk)
}
```

In `all_disk`, I concatenate `boot_disk` and `add_disk`, but before doing the concatenation, I want to check
`if disk_size_gb in add_disk !=null or disk_size_gb!="" or disk_size_gb>0`
then only concatenate like this:

```
all_disk=concat(local.boot_disk,local.add_disk)
```

How to achieve this in Terraform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To deal with `null` and empty strings, you could use the [`coalesce` function](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/coalesce), which:

> takes any number of arguments and returns the first one that isn't null or an empty string.

<sup>*Source: https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/coalesce*</sup>

Then to decide on the concatenation, you could use a [conditional expression](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/conditionals).

```
locals {
  all_disk = (
    coalesce(local.add_disk[0].disk_size_gb, 0) > 0 ?
      concat(local.boot_disk,local.add_disk) :
      local.boot_disk
  )
}
```